# Do I need to account for combinations in this probability calculation?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider a problem of this sort:

> We know that a certain drug has 75% chances of curing a disease. If the drug is administered to 20 patients, what is the probability that exactly 15 of them will be cured?

Now, should the solution be $$0.75^{15}\cdot0.25^{5}$$or  $20\choose15$$\cdot$$0.75^{15}\cdot0.25^{5}$?

If I do need to account for combinations, then why is that?

Comment: Your first calculation computes the probability that a specific group of $15$ is cured.  Note:  you should clarify whether you mean "exactly $15$" or "at least $15$".

Answer (score 1):

You need to account for combinations because the way your wrote your expression could be read as: the first fifteen persons to take the drug are cured and the last five are not.

Since the question says implicitly that any fifteen out of twenty were cured, you need to account for all possible sets of fifteen persons being cured, which is done using combinations (we are choosing without replacement).

Answer (score 1):

As already answered (correctly) by Ertxiem, I just want to elaborate more. Suppose there are three patients, A,B,C. By "drug has 75% chances of curing a disease" means that if the drug is applied to A, he has 75% chance of getting cured, same for B and C. Now the probability of

A getting cured, B getting cured and C not getting cured is 0.75.0.75.0.25.

A getting cured, C getting cured and B not getting cured is 0.75.0.75.0.25.

B getting cured, C getting cured and A not getting cured is 0.75.0.75.0.25.

So finally the total probability of exactly two getting cured is $3 \choose 2$0.75.0.75.0.25